# Bizarre segfault on memcpy in getline

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, getline, memcpy

Consider this bit of stripped-down code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
   FILE * infile;
   char * buffer; // = malloc(sizeof(char));                                 
   ssize_t line_length;
   size_t nbytes;
   int x1;
   int x2;
   //int x3;                                                                 

   infile = fopen("file.txt", "r");
   getline(&buffer, &nbytes, infile);
}
```

As shown, the code runs with no error.

If I uncomment `int x3`, I get a segfault on the `getline` line. I have shown you the entire program here -- `x3` is never used, and I have no idea how this declaration could matter.

I suspect that this is a memory allocation issue, because uncommenting the `= malloc` part removes the segfault.  But what could cause this interaction between `x3` and `getline`?

Comment: *Undefined behavior* is just that ... undefined; anything can happen. Read the docs for `getline` and use it correctly. There's no point in surmising what went wrong when you call it with invalid arguments.

Comment: All the responses were helpful for me.  In particular, this is my first encounter with undefined behavior -- I had not heard of it previously.

Comment: +1 for posting a short, compilable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that both `buffer` and `nbytes` are unitialized. From [`man getline()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline):

> Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size. If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.

`getline()` will be writing to a random location memory (whatever value `buffer` holds) that it has been told is `nbytes` (some unknown value) in size. This is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To correct, initialize the variables to valid values and check the result of `fopen()` before using.